# Difficulties with displaying error messages

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i try to call the form id's and tell the code if i click submit and the username and password fields are empty display "Please enter both login and password." and when there's text on the fields it displays "please stand by" None of this is displaying and i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#login").click(function() {
  $("#login").toggleClass('minus');
         $("form").slideToggle(1000);


 $("form").submit(function(){
    if ("#username" == "" || "#pw" == "") {
      $("#error").text("Please enter both login and password.");
    } else {
      $("#error").text("Please stand by");
    }
     });
  }); // end click
}); // end ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="pw">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="pw" id="pw">
  </p>

  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Submit">
  </p>

  <!-- placeholder for response if form data is correct/incorrect --> 
  <p id="error"> </p>
</form>
```

Comment: How is `"#username"` ever going to be equal to `""`?

Comment: Read and understand this: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: what i mean is if username is equal to nothing then display "Please enter both login and password."

Comment: You should avoid creating a new submit binding every time the login is clicked.

Comment: Also don't forget to cancel the form submit if the error is present.  I assume that's what you would want to do.

Comment: Why is the submit function inside of the onclick handler for an element that does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing the value of these elements but are comparing if f.e. the string "#username" is equal to "", which it of course will never be. You need to actually retrieve the value of your element by using val().

So you might instead do this:

```
if ($("#username").val() == "" || $("#pw").val() == "") {
    $("#error").text("Please enter both login and password.");
}
```

Also maybe have a look at the documentation for further help http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

[Here is fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rL9zvme5/5/)

Also make your input submit button as type "submit" and check the ".val()" of your inputs

```
$("#login").click(function() {
  $("#login").toggleClass('minus');
  $("form").slideToggle(1000);
}); // end click

$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if ( $("#username").val() === "" || $("#pw").val() === "" ) {
    $("#error").text("Please enter both login and password.");
  } else {
    $("#error").text("Please stand by");
  }
});
```

Comment: @Allen Did you check the fiddle?

Comment: yea its working on fiddle but for some reason it isn't working for me locally

Comment: When I was editing your code there were a lot of issues with nesting. Your submit function was wrapped inside click function, so be careful with this.